# Using Firebird within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, firebird

I am working on an Asp.Net Web application project. Now I try to add a chart using data from a database (Firebird).

chart tasks-> configure data source -> new connection -> change data source

I see many data providers but not Firebird! (why?). So I can not launch the query builder.

In additionm in debug mode, I can retrieve data from the database. I think it is about data tool. Why doesn't Visual Studio see FirebirdSql Visual Studio Data Tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install, among .NET provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient), also DDEX Provider. You can download it form http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/.

Comment: the DDEXProvider-3.0.1.0.msi does not work for me, dialog crashes

Answer (score 1):

after installition .NET provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient)and DDEX Provider, i changed  "CodeBase" in FirebirdDDEXProvider32.reg ( for each version of VS u have one reg file. change the one u use) then it is ok now.

it should be like that. show rigth path! and dont forget use double \

Rclick -> open with notpad -> "CodeBase"="D:\\Program Files\\FirebirdClient\\FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll"